# Ayuda..Mezcla de rutas php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

algo raro sucede. Sucede que tengo tres grupos de rutas una para el admin y el otro para secretaria y docente, lo que pasa es que pongo los controllers en cada uno, para que el admin lo pueda tambien ver, pero a  la hora que muestra las vistas, por ejm estoy en modo admin, en la vista alumno y en editar, me sale el url de secretaria. Algo que se mezcla y no se como puedo resolverlo.

VISTA

```
@extends ('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <h4>Lista de Alumnos</h4>
        <a href="alumno/create"><button class="btn btn-success">Nuevo Registro</button></a>
        <h4>@include('matricula.alumno.search')</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-reponsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th>Nombres</th>
                    <th>Apellidos</th>
                    <th>DNI</th>
                    <th>Fecha Nacimiento</th>
                    <th>Sexo</th>
                    <th>Dirección</th>
                    <th>Telefono</th>
                    <th>Apoderado</th>
                    <th>Opciones</th>
                </thead>
                 @foreach($alumnos as $alu) 
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$alu->nombres}}</td>
                    <td>{{$alu->apellidos_pat}} {{$alu->apellidos_mat}}</td>
                    <td>{{$alu->DNI}}</td>
                    <td>{{$alu->fecha_nac}}</td>
                    <td>{{$alu->sexo}}</td>
                    <td>{{$alu->direccion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$alu->telefono}}</td>
                    <td>{{$alu->nombap}} {{$alu->apellido_pat}} {{$alu->apellido_mat}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{URL::action('AlumnoController@edit',$alu->idAlumno)}}"><button class="btn btn-info">Editar</button></a>
                        <a href="" data-target="#modal-delete-{{$alu->idAlumno}}" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @include('matricula.alumno.modal')
                @endforeach 
            </table>
        </div>
    {{$alumnos->render()}}
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

Ruta

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>['auth','administrador'], 'prefix'=>'admin'], function()
{
    Route::resource('añolectivo','AñolectivoController');
    Route::get('matricula/alumno', 'AlumnoController@index');
    Route::get('matricula/alumno/{id}', 'AlumnoController@edit');
    Route::delete('matricula/alumno/{id}', 'AlumnoController@destroy');
    Route::resource('matricula/registro','RegistroController'); 
    Route::resource('matricula/apoderad','ApoderadController');
    Route::resource('ambiente','AmbienteController');
    Route::resource('tambiente','TipoAmbienteController');

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});

Route::group(['middleware' =>['auth','secretario'], 'prefix'=>'secretaria'], function()
{
    Route::get('matricula/alumno', 'AlumnoController@index');
    Route::get('matricula/alumno/{id}', 'AlumnoController@edit');
    Route::resource('matricula/registro','RegistroController'); 
    Route::resource('matricula/apoderad','ApoderadController');
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});

Route::group(['middleware' =>['auth','docente'], 'prefix'=>'docente'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    //Asitencias
    Route::get('cursos', 'AsistenciaController@cursoasig');
    Route::get('asistencia/{id}', 'AsistenciaController@precreate');
    Route::get('asistenciac/{id}', 'AsistenciaController@create');
    Route::post('asistencia/{id}', 'AsistenciaController@store');
 });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es necesario que coloque en tu titulos frases similares a: `ayuda..`, en un lugar que sirve para eso, ya esta por defecto. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo el comportamiento del Laravel es correcto, lo que está haciendo es a la hora de registrar los Routes te sobreescribe los Routes del administrador por los de la secretaría, ya que los dos grupos tienen las rutas identicas. Hay varias soluciones:-

Puedes volver a definir los routes para el administrador o scretaría.
Puedes poner nombres a los Routes de la siguiente manera (**Tienes que poner nombres a  todos las rutas que son identicas en admin y secretaria**):

```
 Route::group(['middleware' =>['auth','administrador'], 'prefix'=>'admin'], function()
{
    Route::get('matricula/alumno', 'AlumnoController@index')->name('admin-matricula');
});

Route::group(['middleware' =>['auth','secretario'], 'prefix'=>'secretaria'], function()
{
    Route::get('matricula/alumno', 'AlumnoController@index')->name('secretaria-matricula');
});
```

y después en el template puedes utilizar el método route('admin-matriucla'). Al método route le puedes pasar parámteros para, mirate la documentación para el uso del método

```
<a href="{{route('admin-matriucla')}}"><button class="btn btn-info">Editar</button></a>
```

Comment: Pero y como hago con esto:     <a href="{{URL::action('AlumnoController@edit',$alu->idAlumno)}}"><button class="btn btn-info">Editar</button></a>   Poniendole esto, <a href="{{route('admin-matriucla')}}"> :V

Comment: <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{route('profile', ['id' => $alu->idAlumno]))}‌​}">Editar</a>